# How to hide or remove shadow or bottomBorder in react-native IOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-router-flux

I am using react-native-router-flux v4.0 library for showing navigation bar in react-native.

Here I created a custom navigation bar.

Here is my code :

```
 _renderLeft() {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={{justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'flex-start', alignSelf: 'flex-start'}}
        onPress={Actions.pop}>
            <Image
                style={{width: 24, height: 24}}
                resizeMode="contain"
                source={require('../../assets/images/ico_swipe.png')}></Image>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

_renderMiddle() {
    return (
        <View style={[styles.navBarTitleView]}>
            <Text style={[styles.navBarTitle]}>{this.props.title}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

_renderRight() {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={{justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'flex-start', alignSelf: 'flex-start'}}
            onPress={Actions.pop}>
            <Image
                style={{width: 24, height: 24}}
                resizeMode="contain"
                source={require('../../assets/images/ico_home.png')}></Image>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

render() {
    StatusBar.setBarStyle('light-content', true);
    return (
        <Header style={[styles.container]}>
            <Left style={{flex: 1}}>
                {this._renderLeft()}
            </Left>
            <Body style={{flex: 3}}>
            <Title style={styles.navBarTitle}>{this.props.title}</Title>
            </Body>
            <Right style={{flex: 1}}>
                {this._renderRight()}
            </Right>
        </Header>
    )
}
```

Here is my Style:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    backgroundColor: AppColors.colorToolBar,
    elevation:0
},
navBarTitleView: {
    flex: 2,
},
navBarTitle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontFamily: AppStyles.fontFamilyMedium,
    color: AppColors.white,
    alignSelf: 'center'
},
menuItem:{
    flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', padding: 20
},
menuTitle:{flex: 20, justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'flex-start'},
menuNextArrow:{flex: 1}
```

});

Here I used it :

```
<Stack key="Key"  hideTabBar>
                <Scene key="Key"
                       navBar={MyCustomNavBarLocation}
                       component={myFileLocation}
                       title="Round 1"
                       onLeft={Actions.pop}
                       BackHandler={Actions.pop}
                       back
                />
            </Stack>
```

I am getting it proper in Android like:

[image]

But in Iphone its not coming proper:

[image]

Here If u see the second Image u saw one grey Line between navigation bar and TimeRemaining view I want to remove that.

Thanks

Comment: Same issue here. I've tried shadowOpacity: 0 and elevation:0 for removing the shadow. But it's not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is in Header component of [NativeBase](https://nativebase.io/)
That bottom border line is coming from the Header style. So according to the issue raised [here](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/724), use,

```
<Header noShadow={true} hasTabs={true}
```

for resolving this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Its late but more accurate answer,
 Add this line in your router to manage shadow:

```
<Router
      navigationBarStyle={{ ...Platform.select({
        ios: {
          //  marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight
          elevation: 0,
          shadowOpacity: 0,
          borderBottomWidth: 0,
        }
      })
    }}
 >
```